# How can I close a Reactjs-popup Modal on Submit?

Tags: reactjs, forms

i've been creating a form using Reactjs-popup, set as a modal, but I can't seem to find a way to both submit the form AND close the modal.
It closes when I click outside the form but it's not very UX... anyone got some tips ? The documentation didn't help much
thanks !!

Comment: add what you have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make use of the `useState` hook in React to track if the model is open or closed. You can set the state when you click on your submit button, or when you close the modal by yourself. It should be pretty flexible and should work for your situation.

Quick example to show the idea:

```
// Create the state hook
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

// Function to close the modal and submit the form
const handleOnClick = () => {
  setIsOpen(false);
  submitForm();
}


<Modal open={isOpen} />
<Button onClick={handleOnClick} text="Submit button" />
```

Comment: that's it ! Thx alot :D
just to be clear, i invoke the modal with a button in one component, but the form and the handleOnClick in another
So i guess I'll need a prop...? or can i use useState across files ?

Comment: Yeah you can just use a prop to do some `prop drilling` on several components or sub-components. I think I would go that way in your situation because it's not that much that you need to do. If you don't like this approach then you could also take a look at the `useContext` hook if you would like to solve it in a more generic way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, because [the modal docs](https://react-popup.elazizi.com/react-modal) make a child modal element as a function, not a react element.

Edit: Comments make me think that I wouldn't have my typescript errors if I used `<Popup modal> {close => .... } </>` instead of  `<Popup modal> (close => .... ) </>` but I haven't tested.

My typescript was complaining about how "type (close: any)=> Element is not assignable to ReactNode" (eg you can't make the Popup component's child be a function! It has to be a JSX Element!)

I confirmed that using a function as a child [is actually intended behavior](https://github.com/yjose/reactjs-popup/blob/master/src/index.tsx#L305-L307) so I just overrode the typescript errors:

```
<Popup modal>
(close => ( 
  my ... modal ... that ... uses ... close 
) )  as unknown as ReactNode
</Popup>
```

and it worked !

So you can use the close function inside your onSubmit function

```
<Popup modal>
(close => ( 
  <yourModal onSubmit={()=> {oldCode; close() }}></yourModal>
) )  as unknown as ReactNode
</Popup>
```

Very bad code smell, but if you just need something to work this will do it.

Comment: Using reactjs-popup as a popup in plain JS I managed like this:

`<Popup> {close => <MyComponent onChange={close} />} </Popup>`